# How can i check for character , number and special characters in a string?

Tags: vb.net, string, validating

I want to user to enter only numbers and characters in textbox i.e no special charaters.
I don't want to use key press event of textbox.

As i need same validation in gridview.

So i want to validate whole string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: windows or web application???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Regex class for regular expressions you can use:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(myString, "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$") Then
    'Do stuff
End If
```

EDIT: I forgot to add the `^` and the `$` to denote that the match should go from start to finish on the string. You'll also need to put a `\s` in there if whitespace is allowed.

Comment: I forgot about Regex's; Joel's answer is much more straightforward than mine :p

Comment: For anyone learning VB like I am, to use this, you may need to import Regex by placing this at the top of the file. `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string and then check the ascii values to make sure they are only Alpha-numeric. Here's some pseudocode:

```
StrLength = Len(Text) 

For x = 1 To StrLength
   sChar = Mid$(Text, x, 1)'Gets the x'th charcter in Text
   bASCII = Asc(sChar)      'Gets ASCII value of character
   if bASCII(not in Range) Then ERROR
Next x
```

Here's a link for to the Ascii Values:
http://www.asciitable.com/